# How can I create a column with time HH:MM from a timestamp column with time HH:MM:SS in my dataset

Tags: javascript, python, sql, r, excel

How can I create a column with time HH:MM from a timestamp column with time HH:MM:SS in my dataset

Comment: Please check edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
df1$col2 <- format(as.POSIXct(as.ITime(df1$col)), "%H:%M")
```

---

Or in `base R` with `sub`

```
df1$col2 <- sub("\\d+$", "", df1$col)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215404/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-how-can-i-create-a-column-with-time-hhmm-from-a-t).